# Method from service layer is not available in controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following service interface:

```
public interface IGrantApplicationService
{
   IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

Here is my implementation of the interface:

```
public class GrantApplicationService : IGrantApplicationService
{
   public IEnumerable<GrantApplication> GetAll()
   {
      // Code here
   }

   public EditGrantApplicationViewModel CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel()
   {
      // Code here
   }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class GrantApplicationController : Controller
{
   private IGrantApplicationService grantApplicationService;

   public GrantApplicationController(IGrantApplicationService grantApplicationService)
   {
      this.grantApplicationService = grantApplicationService;
   }

   public ActionResult Create()
   {
      // I am trying to create my view model like this and populate it with data
      EditGrantApplicationViewModel viewModel = grantApplicationService.CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel();

      return View(viewModel);
   }
}
```

Please see in my Create method, I am trying to create my view model through the service, but when I click . then there doesn't seem to be an option to select CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel, only GetAll is there.  Why is this?  I have all the correct references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define

```
EditGrantApplicationViewModel CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel();
```

on your `IGrantApplicationService` interface.

At the moment the controller only knows about what is on the interface not the class.

Comment: I do inject a GrantApplicationService instance.

Comment: But your definition only has the FindAll() method - the compiler doesn't know what implementation of that interface will be passed in at compile-time. You'd have to invoke the method via reflection (which would be an anti-pattern in this circumstance)

Answer (score 1):

Your `grantApplicationService` field is declared as `IGrantApplicationService`  but your method `CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel` is not in the interface. Just add `CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel` in the interface and you'll be fine.